# Replacing with sed a string containing parenthesis with a substring of contained date into the parenthesis

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to replace with "sed" a string containing parenthesis with a part of the contained string into the parenthesis.

Input

> to_date('04/10/12','DD/MM/RR')

Output

> '04/10/12'

Is it possible? How?

Multiple occurrences can exist in the input

I tried

```
sed -e 's/to_date(//'' -e 's/,\'DD/MM/RR\')//g'
```

but I would like a one substitute expression

Comment: yes, I tried -e 's/to_date(//'' -e 's/,\'DD/MM/RR\')//g' but I would like a one substitute expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -E "s/to_date\(('[^']+')[^)]*\)/\1/g" <<< "to_date('04/10/12','DD/MM/RR')"

'04/10/12'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed too

```
sed -E "s/[^']*('[^']*').*/\1/" <<< "to_date('04/10/12','DD/MM/RR')"
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine too. Is it possible to mix -E and -e options in a sed command ? I've tried it but I have a strange error message: "No such file or directory"

Comment: Yes, It's possible.Give a example of a line where you get this error message.

Comment: Here's an example: sed -E "s/[^']*('[^']*').*/\1/" -e 's/12/13/' <<< "to_date('04/10/12','DD/MM/RR')"

Comment: Use it this way : sed -E -e "s/[^']*('[^']*').*/\1/" -e 's/12/13/' <<< "to_date('04/10/12','DD/MM/RR')"

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand now the meaning of "-E". anubhava's answer is better in the sens that it doesn't remove existing strings located before and after the the "to_date" in the same line.